# Broken layout XML LUMA CE2.4.6-p2

Tags: magento2.4, 2.4.6-p2

Broken layout XML files after installing Magento 2.4.6 on Ubuntu 22.04 Nginx, PHP 8.1.

domain: kiqlik.com

Looks all good in the front...

```
/var/www/html/2.4.6-p2$ cd /var/www/html/2.4.6-p2/var/log
deborah@webserver-magento-poc:/var/www/html/2.4.6-p2/var/log$ tail -f system.log
[2023-11-24T22:32:49.257513+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.actions.toolbar' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'page.main.actions' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-11-24T22:32:49.257567+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.left' tries to reorder itself towards '', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-11-24T22:32:49.257609+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'header.inner.right' tries to reorder itself towards 'header.inner.left', but their parents are different: 'header' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-11-24T22:32:49.257660+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'notification.messages' tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and '' respectively. [] []
[2023-11-24T22:45:07.852858+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-11-24T22:45:07.853074+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-11-24T22:45:07.853223+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-11-24T22:45:07.853285+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'paypal.partner.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-11-24T22:45:07.853327+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'bml.right.logo' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2023-11-24T22:45:07.853367+00:00] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sidebar.container.paylater' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
```

Tried:

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento module:status

```
List of disabled modules:
Magento_OpenSearch
Magento_TwoFactorAuth
```

I am thinking it is a Luma problem?